# How to reactively set a <html> class

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have 2 themes: 'light-theme', 'dark-theme'
I would like to set the `<html class="">` according to a value i have in my vuex store. Like `darkMode: true`

How can i set the `<html>` class reactively like that?

(using vue3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple javascript for it.

Just add a button or toggle for theme change like:

```
<button @click="changeTheme">Change Theme</button>
```

and inside this component add `changeTheme` method inside methods:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute( 'class', 'newThemeClass' );
```

Or just add watcher to your store value and change according to it:

```
computed:{
    ...mapGetters(["yourGetterName"])
 },
watch: {
    darkMode(value) {
      document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].setAttribute( 'class', value );
    },
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Vue docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes), there are following ways to do this.

1.Binding to Objects

```
<div :class="{ 'active-class': isActive }"></div>
```

The above syntax means the presence of the 'active-class' class will be determined by the truthiness of the data property isActive.

2.Binding to Arrays

```
<div :class="[isActive ? activeClass : '', errorClass]"></div>
```

This will always apply errorClass, but activeClass will only be applied when isActive is truthy.